# Can any functions be expressed in one formula? (without conditions)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, functional-equations, collatz-conjecture

This is the extension of my previous inquiry:

[Is it possible to describe the Collatz function in one formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449874/is-it-possible-to-describe-the-collatz-function-in-one-formula][1])

---

Can each of all functions be expressed in one formula?
That is, can any function expressed with conditions(e.g. modular or interval conditions) be expressed without conditions or sub-functions?

For example, conditional function f(x) which
$$f\left(n\right) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x<-1\\ 1 & \text{if } -1≤x<0 \\ 2 & \text{if } 0≤x<1 \\ 3 & \text{if } 1≤x \end{cases}$$
Can be described by

$$f\left(x\right)=\left[\arctan  \left(x\tan \left(1\right)\right)\right]+2$$

Comment: What is a "formula" to you? This: $$\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x<-1\\ 1 & \text{if } -1≤x<0 \\ 2 & \text{if } 0≤x<1 \\ 3 & \text{if } 1≤x \end{cases}$$ looks like a perfectly good formula to me.

Comment: Formula without any conditions

Comment: x @Bingkongmaster: Then I define the symbol $\mathrm{KhwR}$ to mean the precise function you speak about here, and then $$f(x)=\mathrm{KhwR}(x)$$ is a formula that does not contain any conditions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But conditions are implied in KhwR(x) whereas [arctan(xtan(1))]+2 is not

Comment: x @Bing: Then I am still waiting for your definition of what qualifies as a "formula" to you. So far what you have said is not operational; the only way to know whether you consider something to be a "formula" is to ask you. That is not a definition that anyone else than you can reasonably use for anything.

Comment: x @Bing: In particular, you have not described why you think $\mathrm{KhwR}$ is a less acceptable symbol to use in a "formula" than $[\cdot]$ is. Both of them are merely names for certain piecewise constant functions, and $\mathrm{KhwR}$ is even simpler because it has a finite number of pieces rather than infinitely many for $[\cdot]$. Then what makes one but not the other acceptable for use in a "formula"? It is impossible to know what your conditions for acceptable functions are as long as you don't reveal your criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, despite my inability to adequately explain. What I mean by a formula without conditions is a formula that can be described exclusively by calculations, which does not include the if statement.

Comment: The point is, whether calculations can express if conditions. For example, modular if conditions can be expressed by trigonometric calculations.

Comment: You keep focusing on what you _don't_ allow, but in order to properly define a class of formulas you're interested in, you have to define precisely what you _do_ allow. You seem to be extremely unwilling to do that, but until you do so, your question is not an answerable one. (And you did not reply to my question about which property the $[\cdot]$ function has that makes you accept it when you don't accept $\mathrm{KhwR}$.)

Comment: And now you also need to provide a definition of what "calculation" means to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow the floor function (as you do in your example), one can easily express indicator fucntions of intervals:
$${\bf 1}_{[0,\infty)}(x) =\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\ge0$}\\0&\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}=1+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2+x^2}\right\rfloor$$
and then 
$$\begin{align}
{\bf 1}_{[a,\infty)}(x)&={\bf 1}_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)\\
{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,a)}(x)&=1-{\bf 1}_{[a,\infty)}(x)\\
{\bf 1}_{(a,\infty)}(x)&={\bf 1}_{(-\infty,-a)}(-x)\\
{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,a]}(x)&={\bf 1}_{[-a,\infty)}(-x)\\
{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}(x)&={\bf 1}_{[a,\infty)}(x)\cdot{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,b]}(x)\\
{\bf 1}_{(a,b]}(x)&={\bf 1}_{(a,\infty)}(x)\cdot{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,b]}(x)\\
{\bf 1}_{[a,b)}(x)&={\bf 1}_{[a,\infty)}(x)\cdot{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,b)}(x)\\
{\bf 1}_{(a,b)}(x)&={\bf 1}_{(a,\infty)}(x)\cdot{\bf 1}_{(-\infty,b)}(x)\\
\end{align}$$
so that we can express indicator functions of arbitrary intervals.
Then in principle you can build your function by multiplying with such indicator functions.
However, you may need to be careful with psrts that areundefined in points outside the interval they are used in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, using the same technique, can function of any conditions also be expressed in one formula without conditions or sub-intervals? For example, can floor function be used to also express the Collatz function? (which uses modular condition)

Comment: @Bingkongmaster Actually, why do you accept $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and not $\cdot\bmod \cdot$? -- Also, my hints were aimed at functions defined on $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb Z$ (and not $\Bbb C$). Periodic indicator functions can be found using sines and cosines, good enough for functions on $\Bbb Z$ but a horrendously stupid thing to do IMHO,

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find a clever formula to express the step function $H(x)=[x\ge0]$. $H(x)=\dfrac{x+|x|}{2x}$ almost does it. See also [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Given that, then:

- $H(x-a)$ is the characteristic function of $[a,\infty)$
- $H(a-x)$ is the characteristic function of $(-\infty,a]$
- $H(x-a)(b-x)$ is the characteristic function of $[a,b]$

and so any function that is defined piecewise can be written using a linear combination of suitable $H$: if your function is equal to $h(x)$ in an interval $[a,b]$, just add $H(x-a)(b-x)h(x)$.

For instance, your function is
$$
H(-1-x)\cdot 0+
H(x+1)H(0-x)\cdot 1+
H(x-0)H(1-x)\cdot 2+
H(x-1)\cdot 3
$$

But it does not seem worth the trouble when the piecewise definition is so much clearer.

Comment: Good point! Do you think it is also possible to find the formula for other functions with conditions as well?

Comment: @Bingkongmaster, sure, just add $H(x−a)(b−x)h(x)$.

Comment: @Inf sorry, I mean other kind of functions with conditions like modular conditions

Comment: @Bingkongmaster, in the general case I think you need  Iverson bracket.